# Android: Remove the top bar from an app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove the top bar from the app. I try to write in the xml file

```
<activity

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

</activity>
```

But it give me the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I also try do use the code after OnCreate method:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

But it also crash....how can i do? Thanks!

Comment: set `anroid:theme.Appcompat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the default theme in AndroidManifest file. There is only one reason you are seeing the title bar.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And you could add

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It is because your activity is extending ActionBarActivity. You could replace by extending Activity for your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok it works...but a question? What are screenOrientation and configChanges?

Comment: I wanted to lock the scree orientation so that any change in configuration doesn't restart by activity. Please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html. upvote is appreciated. :)